# Making a Java library "Groovy"

Tags: groovy

I fell in love with Groovy and try to use it more and more. Now I have to work with Oracle Forms Jdapi library. When working with this library, you write a lot of code like this:

```java
JdapiIterator progIterator = getWorkForm().getProgramUnits();
while(progIterator.hasNext()) {
    ProgramUnit currProgUnit = (ProgramUnit) progIterator.next();
    ...
}
```

and of cource I would like to write

```groovy
getWorkForm().programUnits.each {
    ...
}
```

However, I never wrote a Groovy interface to an existing Java library and need some assistance. I know about [Groovy 2.0's extension methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.0+release+notes#Groovy20releasenotes-Extensionmodules), but in that case I am thinking about a class with the same name in a different namespace which delegates only to the functions I would like to keep.

What is the best approach for providing the `each` functionality, but also all other closures applicable for collections? I would appreciate if you point me in the right direction!

Comment: Can't you write `getWorkForm().programUnits.each { ProgramUnit currProgUnit -> ... }` already? What error do you get?

Comment: Yeah, I do this sort of thing all the time. The above code should work as expected. No need to write an interface wrapper unless you want to add some helper methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only method you need to provide is the `iterator()` method. You then get all of the Groovy Object iteration methods (`each()`, `find()`, `any()`, `every()`, `collect()`, ...) for free!

Comment: I thought you could `each` on an iterator too, ie: `0.with { x -> ([ hasNext:{ x < 10 }, next:{ x++ } ] as Iterator).each { println it } }`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this feature. After digging in I found the implementation (at least in the Groovy JDK doku) in java.lang.Class. I thought I have to implement much more!